# Php Script Show Error of divide by zero where is varible has a value greater than zero

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.8, divide-by-zero

I have an array `$arr = array(0,0,0,0,5);`
i am using `array_sum` for above array to calculate the sum.

```
$temp = array_sum($arr);
```

when I divide that with `any_value/ $temp;`

Php Laravel Shows me an error.

I don't know whats wrong with that. I have tried many other ways but same results.

Comment: Which error show?

Comment: The code you show works, the error must be elsewhere. Show more of your code.

Comment: Error is Divide by Zero. while issue is stil same Can't divide the the value